# How to count number of numeric values in a row

Tags: r, dataframe, count, bioinformatics

I have a data frame like this

```
df <- as.data.frame(read.table(text =
                    "Human_Gene_Name    Human    Mouse    Chicken    Worm
                  Gene_1    8.5    7.0    NA    5.0
                  Gene_2    5.5    NA    NA    NA", header  = T))
```

I need to count the number of numeric values in each row and then add an extra column to my data frame with that value. So for Gene_1 one it would be 3 and for Gene_2 it would be 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take the row sums of the result from `!is.na(df)` with the first column removed.

```
rowSums(!is.na(df[-1]))
# [1] 3 1
```